# How to access the event in the updated?

Tags: vuejs2

In `methods` we can access the `event` directly

```
methods : {
    opcoes (event) {

      console.log(event);

    }
  }
```

But I need to access the `event` on the `updated` is it possible?

```
updated() {
    console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get changes in Vue updated hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43764105/how-to-get-changes-in-vue-updated-hook)

Comment: `updated` is triggered by Vue and is not passed an `event` object.