# Vue - What is triggering a state change?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, developer-tools

I have a vue (Nuxt 2) app and something is triggering a state change.
My `console.log()` in page component is showing an update.

```
updated() {
  console.log('UPDATED');
}
```

I know that I can use the Vue Developer-Tool (I use Firefox) and switch to "Timeline" to see all the state changes.

I disabled the only thing that updated the store, but my page component(s) still get updated.

Are there other ways to see what triggers a state change or which values have changes?

In my case I have an array of data I get from my headless CMS by API call which is missing data in the `updated()` hook.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get changes in Vue updated hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43764105/how-to-get-changes-in-vue-updated-hook)

Comment: Thank you. Helped only a bit. I know what data is changed. I just don't know what request that triggers the update.